# open a new fully featured browser window with javascript for selenium testcase

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In a chrome window, if you do Ctrl+N (on windows) you'll get an additional window, with extensions loaded, toolbar etc.

How do you spawn this with javascript?

At present, I've tried:

```
window.open("about:blank", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,titlebar=yes,resizable=yes");
```

This does not achieve the desired equivalent of Ctrl+N.